Enforce reauthentication using Apache2 OpenID-Connect and an Entra ID OIDC provider
My web users have accounts in Entra ID so my web sites allow them to log in using Microsoft's Entra ID as an OpenID-Connect provider.
My apache2 web servers use mod_auth_openidc to support the Microsoft login, and this works great.
Some web sites are considered "high security", and when visiting those sites I'd like to continue to use the Microsoft login, but force web users to reauthenticate (and ideally force MFA to happen again too). (It might be acceptable to enforce that a "sufficiently recent" login has occurred.)
I understand it may be possible to use a "max_age=0" parameter to force reauthentication, but how should this be configured in practice?
I tried to configure this as part of the redirect URI of my application registration in Azure (and on my Apache server), but that doesn't allow me to include parameters in the URI. I did notice there's support to send back a "max_age" claim so I feel I'm getting close to the right thing, but I'd appreciate a clue from anyone who has this working.
